# Is asking about hypocritical behaviour off topic? (#2)

Tags: discussion

Follow up to the [original question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6149/is-asking-about-hypocritical-behaviour-off-topic).

I followed Ted Wrigley's template when asking [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72830/why-does-australia-not-tolerate-china-building-a-base-in-solomon-islands-if-they): two sentences describing the behavior followed by "What factors caused this difference in approach?" and the result is the same, the question is closed as a push question.

I would like to understand the difference.

Edit: the question has been reopened ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is asking about hypocritical behaviour off topic?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6149/is-asking-about-hypocritical-behaviour-off-topic)

Comment: I am voting to close this as a duplicate question as I see no reason why it is different.

Comment: I would say that question still is bad as it is asking about two different types of behavior one being violent action through an invasion and the other being non violent action through words and warnings.

Answer (score 4):

I obviously can't speak for every user who downvoted or voted to close, but from what I saw in the comments (and my own interpretation) the problem isn't that you asked about hypocritical behavior, but that the behavior you described wasn't hypocritical.

In your question, you said was Australia doing two things that you believed was hypocritical:

- Australia condemned and sanctioned Russia in response to their invasion of Ukraine
- Australia's Minister for Defence said Australia should be prepared for war as a response to China's expanding influence

The two behaviors you described are essentially "Russia shouldn't have invaded Ukraine" and "we should be prepared for war with China". These two policies didn't really seem like contradictory or hypocritical to me, and judging by some of the comments other users felt the same way.

However, as the other meta post you linked says asking about hypocritical behaviors/policies isn't off-topic by default, and I can see a couple ways you could ask about potential hypocrisy in Australia's behavior towards China/Russia

- If Australia condemned/sanctioned Russia for preparing for a potential war with NATO, you could ask why Australia would prepare for a potential war with China in the same way
- If Australia invades the Solomon Islands to stop the deal with China (or if they did a comparable military operation in the past), then you can ask why they condemned/sanctioned Russia for doing the same in Ukraine

Comment: I think it needs to be strongly remembered that we are talking about one country taking action by invading and another country talking about a red line and war but no actual invasion of the islands in question.

Comment: I made no assertion in the question that the behavior was hypocritical (try Ctrl + F for that phrase). Your answer here also seems more like an answer to the linked question than to this one. But I don't have anything more to say about both questions; they seem to have run their course.

Comment: It's an SE question and the purpose of a question is to facilitate answer posting. There's no "should" or "shouldn't" in the question. "In your question, you said was Australia doing two things *that you believed was hypocritical:*..." No, that simply did not happen. It's not there. The question is non-accusatory and impartial and allows for any residual premise to be addressed in answers. We should not presume to know the thoughts and feelings of other users. "You seem to think that..." type assertions should be avoided everywhere in Stack Exchange. Stick to the actual words written.

Comment: @uhoh: Since this meta post was titled "Is asking about hypocritical behaviour off topic?" and references another meta post titled "Is asking about hypocritical behaviour off topic?", I'll admit that I jumped to the conclusion that they thought the question they linked was asking about hypocritical behavior, and they wanted to know if it was off-topic.

Comment: Well there are several separate issues here that relate to the use of "about" in the title of this meta question. What others might feel that a question is *about* is not necessarily at all what a question actually asks. Look again at the question in the main site: "[Why does A not tolerate B if they think C should tolerate D?...What factors (other than self-interest) explain this difference in approach?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/72830/16047)" There is no premise of presence nor absence of hypocrisy in that question, likewise [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/70784/16047)

Comment: So while some might see the greater issue discussed in meta as whether we are worried about the on-topic-ness of questions about *hypocritical* behavior, others only see a question about *inconsistency*. Nonetheless the word "hypocritical" became associated with the hand-wringing due to the choice of the previous meta question's *title*, and this  meta question has simply indicated the connection to it by repeating its title and appending "(#2)". (An SE question is not its title, it's the entire post, the title sometimes only hints at what the question post is truly "about")

Comment: Note that [this answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6151/16047) to the previous meta question also invoke the "seem to think" technique to project intent where none existed: "The way @uhoh asked his question:... Seems to make that equivalence presumption, pushing the reader towards an assumption of hypocrisy." We shouldn't answer titles, we shouldn't project, presume, or mind-read. My goodness, it seems I'm suddenly seeing [originalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Originalism) in a whole new light! :-)